# Git - efficient way to add files in commandline

Tags: git, command-line

I prefer using my Git commandline, feels like I know what I am doing (or if not, I can only blame myself...).

Still, it always feels like `git add`-ing files is the least efficient thing to do.

I do not like the `-a` option, especially when I really do not mean to add all files. I do like the `-i` feature that allows me to add all files just by typing numbers (or just add snippets).

But just adding let's say four files feels like a pain - have to `git status`, then copy/paste etc...

Ayn tips? better workflow?

Comment: I must own this is the *only* operation I leave to a GUI (gitg) because it's way more faster to select the ones desired and double-click than anything I found on the command line.

Comment: I often use `git add -u` : add to index tracked file ; otherwise, I use `git status` (`gits status -sb` gives a more compact output) and select+middle click to select individual files

Answer (score 2):

You can add files using [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) pattern this is extension of shell but not the git itself.

For example if you have

```
src/files-I-want-to-commit/file1
src/files-I-want-to-commit/file2
src/files-I-want-to-commit/file3
src/files-I-Dont-want-to-commit/file
```

You can simply do

```
git add src/files-I-want-to-commit/
```

If you have:

```
src/files-I-want-to-commit/commit_file1
src/files-I-want-to-commit/oh-I-dont-want-to-commit-that
src/files-I-want-to-commit/and-that
```

You can then do:

```
git add src/files-I-want-to-commit/commit_*
```

And so on.