# git add a lot of files but not all files from "Changes not staged for commit"

Tags: git, version-control, command-line-interface

I have around 100 files which I want to stage for a commit but there are around 5 files I don't want to commit.
What is the best approach here so I do not have to add each file separately?

Is there an easy way to first add them all and then undo `git add` again for the 5 files I don't want to be committed in cli?

Comment: `git reset` can undo `git add`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - efficient way to add files in commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584245/git-efficient-way-to-add-files-in-commandline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could (temporarily) ignore the files.

Or use

```
git add .
```

to add them all and

```
git reset HEAD <file name>
```

for all files you want not to be commited.

Comment: I ended up using this approach because the files I worked with had a lot of different paths and using wildcards/globs pattern would have taken me longer in the end.